# Flutter spaceBetween doesn't work in Column inside Card widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a Card widget with two columns of information. The left-most Column contains a line of text above an Icon - I want the text at the top of the Card and the Icon at the bottom. The height of the Card is given by the right-hand Column (which has a larger Icon and a line of Text underneath it). But I can't get `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to do its job - the first Column stays squashed together, either at the top / centre / bottom depending on how I set the crossAxisAlignment of the enclosing Row.

I've tried putting a SizedBox between the Text and the Icon and this does indeed space them out - but the whole point of coding layout is that it should be able to infer those spaces. I don't want to hardcode it; it is defined by the size of the Card based on the larger right-hand column.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class CardTestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardTestWidgetState createState() => _CardTestWidgetState();
}

class _CardTestWidgetState extends State<CardTestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5.0,
        horizontal: 15.0,
      ),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 7.5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 15.0,
            horizontal: 20.0,
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text('Test A'),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.podcast, color: Colors.blueAccent, size: 72.0,),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                    child: Text('Podcast'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the text 'Test A' and the Star icon should be at the top and bottom respectively of their column. How can I force this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your `Row` into an `IntrinsicHeight` and your two `Columns` into two `Expanded` then it should work fine.

**Here is the code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class CardTestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardTestWidgetState createState() => _CardTestWidgetState();
}

class _CardTestWidgetState extends State<CardTestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5.0,
        horizontal: 15.0,
      ),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 7.5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 15.0,
            horizontal: 20.0,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 8.0,
                        ),
                        child: Text('Test A'),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.podcast,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          size: 72.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                        child: Text('Podcast'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As the document says, "This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible".